# Anylogic microsoft sql error The index 1 is out of range

Tags: java, sql-server, anylogic

I am using an external database with [AnyLogic](https://www.anylogic.com/) to check If data exists in a database. If it does not then I need to insert and perform another operation. However I am getting this error

> jdbc.SQLServerException: The index 1 is out of range.

This is my code.

```
try {
    Connection con = vanet.getConnection();
          java.sql.Statement stmt=null;
          java.sql.ResultSet rs=null;

    String preQueryStatement
          = "SELECT * FROM vanet WHERE vehicle = " + vehicle.getIndex() + ";";

          PreparedStatement pStmnt = con.prepareStatement(preQueryStatement);
            pStmnt.setInt(1, vehicle.getIndex());

         rs = pStmnt.executeQuery();
            if (!rs.next())
            {
                String insertStatement
                = "INSERT INTO vanet VALUES (vehicle, surrounded)";
                PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(insertStatement);

                ps.setInt(1, vehicle.getIndex());
                ps.setInt(2, v.getIndex());

                System.out.println("new user inserted");
            }  
      }catch(SQLException e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here is the full error message

```
The index 1 is out of range.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:226)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.setterGetParam(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:1110)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.setValue(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:1124)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.setInt(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:1406)
    at v2v_simple.TaskAssignment.enterState(TaskAssignment.java:425)
    at v2v_simple.TaskAssignment.executeActionOf(TaskAssignment.java:651)
    at com.anylogic.engine.TransitionMessage.execute(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Your queries aren't currently using the `?` placeholders system.  For instance, the first one could look like `"SELECT * FROM vanet WHERE vehicle = ? "` .

Comment: have u replaced  String insertStatement
                = "INSERT INTO vanet VALUES (vehicle, surrounded)"; this with placeholder ? also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this,

```
String preQueryStatement
      = "SELECT * FROM vanet WHERE vehicle = ? ";

      PreparedStatement pStmnt = con.prepareStatement(preQueryStatement);
        pStmnt.setInt(1, vehicle.getIndex());
```

Comment: Thanks the error has gone, although it is not inserting data into database.

Comment: you will have to do pStmnt.executeQuery();

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use something like this:

```
pStmnt.setInt(1, vehicle.getIndex());
```

You need to have a placeholder (`?` symbol) in your query. It should look something like this:

```
String preQueryStatement = "SELECT * FROM vanet WHERE vehicle = ? ";
```

The same goes for the second statement as well but I think you can handle it from here :)

A sidenote: in general you should never concatenate SQL statements and always use placeholders instead. It might cause a security flaw in your application.